# Pyspark - REST API call to get azure service bus connection string

Tags: python, databricks, azureservicebus

I am trying to send messages using Databricks to Azure Service bus topic using connection string defined in the Pyspark code/using key vault. As per client policy they will be updating the keys frequently so has asked to use REST API calls to get the connection string from the service bus everytime we need to send a message!

Is there any way I can do this using rest API calls?

Comment: Unless the keys are actually part of the connection string, why would that need to change?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use ListKeys api call from the management.azure.com REST API to list them, see below
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/servicebus/stable/disaster-recovery-configs/list-keys